# How to add XFF headers in angular response?

Tags: angular

console.log(response) didnt show my x_forwarded_for headers

I already activate it in load balancer, server, and nginx, and all confirmed that XFF have been activated.

but my when i tried to console.log(response) from frontend i didnt get the XFF header

how to add XFF header? is it must be from server, frontend, or backend?

Comment: It makes no sense to see a xff header in client, it is used to forward client information (ip address) to backend system behind load balancer, nginx etc. so you need to test there not in client